# KendoUI tooltip overflows window

Tags: kendo-ui, tooltip, overflow, kendo-tooltip

I have a kendo tooltip for a field, that can contain a very long values. The default position of the tooltip is on the left of the field, however, if there's not enough space for a tooltip on the left, it automatically switches to the right. The problem i have, that sometimes, there's not enough space for a tooltip on the right either. I want to somehow control the behaviour of the tooltip in that case, and position it the way i want. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and found the code to dynamically place a tooltip. Perhaps this will help you.

```
var p = $(SomeWrapper).offset();
$(element).kendoTooltip({
    top: p.top,
    left: p.left,
    frame: false,
    callout: false,
    show: function (e) {
        e.sender.popup.element.css('margin-top', '-10px');
        e.sender.popup.element.css('margin-left', p.left + 'px');
    },
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    position: "bottom"
});
```